# Importance of $\det(A^TA)$ in practical discussions

Tags: matrices, determinant, positive-semidefinite

Let us assume that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. It is known that since $A^TA$ is symmetric positive semi-definite, $\mathrm{det}(A^TA)$ is non-negative. I would like to know what is the importance of $\mathrm{det}(A^TA)$ in practical discussions?

Moreover, can we draw a specific conclusion about the relationship between $\mathrm{det}(A^TA)$ and the entries of A? For example, can we conclude that if the amount of $\mathrm{det}(A^TA)$ tends to zero, then the entries of $A$ also tends to zero?

Comment: $det(A^T A) = det(A)^2$. If this tends to zero, then $A$ tends to becoming singular.

Comment: Even if $A$ is a diagonal matrix, $\det (A^T A) = 0$ does not say much about *all* entries of $A$. For example (assuming by "tending to" you're referring to sequences of matrices),

$$A_n = \pmatrix{a & 0 \\ 0 & \tfrac{1}{n}}$$

has the property that $\det(A_n) \to 0$, no matter what $a$ is.

Comment: Aside from abstract properties which are often established near the outset of the discussion of a determinant, there is generally fairly little relationship between the determinant of a matrix product and individual entries of the matrices that form that product. I think of the determinant as a soup. All of the ingredients (matrix entries) contribute into the soup. It's hard to back out anything in particular.